# What options do I have for installing istio, either without istioctl, or with istioctl installed on an admin node outside cluster

Tags: istio

I dont want to install istioctl in on nodes in my k8s cluster.

I'd strongly prefer to use it to create yaml that I can then install with kubectl.

Alternatively I'd like to use it on an administrative node separate from the cluster itself.

Most of the documentation is focused on the use of istioctl, and though it doesnt state this explicitly, I'm pretty sure it assumes you install istioctl on one of the master nodes.

Though hopefully my assumption is wrong.

Reading [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/) link it seems that maybe I can install istioctl on my admin node, and it will install everything on the cluster referenced in my .kube folder (just as kubectl does)

So my two questions are:

1. Can I use istioctl installed on an admin node outside of my
   kubernetes cluster (i use k3s) and then have it install stuff into
   my cluster. (I administer my cluster from an admin node separate
   from the cluster
2. Is there good documentation for doing the complete
   install using kubectl, and only using istioctl to generate yaml

A separate question I have relates to the ISTIO operator that I saw. I believe that the ISTIO team has deprecated their operator. Did I misinterpret what I read? I've been in the habit of looking for operators to install the components of my system. They seem to be the way the K8S *standard* is driving things.

---

Possible answer to Question 1 above.

In follow up. I've gone ahead and installed istioctl on an admin node outside my cluster. So far it would seem that it is able to communicate with my cluster fine. Though I've not yet performed an install with istioctl, it would seem that the following command says "good to go"

```
/usr/local/istio/istio/bin/istioctl

(base) [dsargrad@localhost ~]$ istioctl x precheck

✔ No issues found when checking the cluster. Istio is safe to install or upgrade!

  To get started, check out https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm pretty sure it assumes you install istioctl on one of the master nodes. Though hopefully my assumption is wrong.

You're in luck, this assumption is wrong. You do not need to install istioctl on the Kubernetes control plane nodes.

> Can I use istioctl installed on an admin node outside of my kubernetes cluster

Yes. It is meant to be used like kubectl, either run manually or as part of a CD pipeline.

> Is there good documentation for doing the complete install using kubectl, and only using istioctl to generate yaml

Good is subjective, but [this section](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#generate-a-manifest-before-installation) contains the steps you're looking for.

> I believe that the ISTIO team has deprecated their operator. Did I misinterpret what I read?

Yes. It is not deprecated, however its use is "discouraged". The operator was developed back when the istio control plane was separated into  different components (galley, pilot, mixer, and citadel) and managing them all was a lot more work. Much of the control plane was later [consolidated into a single component called istiod](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/istiod/) which simplified things considerably.

You are still welcome to use the operator. It contains all the same logic that istioctl does, it just runs it for you in a control loop.

Comment: rsalmond: thanks very much for your thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 1):

istioctl generates istio related manifests.  Run

```
istioctl manifest generate —set profile=demo > istio-demo.yaml
```

Then you can take file into k8s environment where you run kubectl apply -f istio-demo.yaml which will install istio into cluster

Comment: thanks very much. i'll plan to try this. though I've learned that im quite happy using istioctl on a separate admin node.

Answer (score 0):

In short, istioctl is able to install into a separate cluster seemingly quite cleanly:

```
(base) [dsargrad@localhost samples]$ istioctl install

This will install the Istio 1.14.1 default profile with ["Istio core" "Istiod" "Ingress gateways"] components into the cluster. Proceed? (y/N) y

✔ Istio core installed                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
✔ Istiod installed                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
✔ Ingress gateways installed                                                                                                                                                                                                             
✔ Installation complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Making this installation the default for injection and validation.

Thank you for installing Istio 1.14.  Please take a few minutes to tell us about your install/upgrade experience!  https://forms.gle/yEtCbt45FZ3VoDT5A

(base) [dsargrad@localhost samples]$ k get namespaces

NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   5d12h
kube-system       Active   5d12h
kube-public       Active   5d12h
kube-node-lease   Active   5d12h
rook-ceph         Active   5d7h
istio-system      Active   35s
```

And the resources in the istio-system namespace, all seem quite healthy. Additionally the ingress-gateway seems to have been properly exposed (via LoadBalancer) to the public interface

```
(base) [dsargrad@localhost samples]$ k get all -n istio-system

NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/istiod-859b487f84-xh4nz                 1/1     Running   0          3m8s
pod/svclb-istio-ingressgateway-6z45f        3/3     Running   0          2m54s
pod/svclb-istio-ingressgateway-pt94b        3/3     Running   0          2m54s
pod/istio-ingressgateway-57598d7c8b-shgtw   1/1     Running   0          2m54s


NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                     PORT(S)                                      AGE
service/istiod                 ClusterIP      10.43.145.104   <none>                          15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP        3m8s
service/istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.43.3.172     192.168.56.133,192.168.56.134   15021:31786/TCP,80:30752/TCP,443:31197/TCP   2m54s


NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/svclb-istio-ingressgateway   2         2         2       2            2           <none>          2m54s


NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/istiod                 1/1     1            1           3m8s
deployment.apps/istio-ingressgateway   1/1     1            1           2m55s

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/istiod-859b487f84                 1         1         1       3m8s
replicaset.apps/istio-ingressgateway-57598d7c8b   1         1         1       2m55s


NAME                                                       REFERENCE                         TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istio-ingressgateway   Deployment/istio-ingressgateway   2%/80%    1         5         1          2m54s
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istiod                 Deployment/istiod                 0%/80%    1         5         1          3m8s
```

Lastly a verification of the installation seems healthy:

```
(base) [dsargrad@localhost kubernetes]$ istioctl verify-install

1 Istio control planes detected, checking --revision "default" only
components.pilot.k8s.replicaCount should not be set when values.pilot.autoscaleEnabled is true

✔ HorizontalPodAutoscaler: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Deployment: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system checked successfully
✔ PodDisruptionBudget: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Role: istio-ingressgateway-sds.istio-system checked successfully
✔ RoleBinding: istio-ingressgateway-sds.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Service: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ServiceAccount: istio-ingressgateway-service-account.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRole: istiod-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRole: istio-reader-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRoleBinding: istio-reader-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRoleBinding: istiod-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ServiceAccount: istio-reader-service-account.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Role: istiod-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ RoleBinding: istiod-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ServiceAccount: istiod-service-account.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: wasmplugins.extensions.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: destinationrules.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: envoyfilters.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: gateways.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: proxyconfigs.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: serviceentries.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: sidecars.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: virtualservices.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: workloadentries.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: workloadgroups.networking.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: authorizationpolicies.security.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: peerauthentications.security.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: requestauthentications.security.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: telemetries.telemetry.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ CustomResourceDefinition: istiooperators.install.istio.io.istio-system checked successfully
✔ HorizontalPodAutoscaler: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRole: istiod-clusterrole-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRole: istiod-gateway-controller-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRoleBinding: istiod-clusterrole-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRoleBinding: istiod-gateway-controller-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ConfigMap: istio.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Deployment: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ConfigMap: istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system checked successfully
✔ MutatingWebhookConfiguration: istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system checked successfully
✔ PodDisruptionBudget: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRole: istio-reader-clusterrole-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ClusterRoleBinding: istio-reader-clusterrole-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Role: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ RoleBinding: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ Service: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ServiceAccount: istiod.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: stats-filter-1.11.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: tcp-stats-filter-1.11.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: stats-filter-1.12.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: tcp-stats-filter-1.12.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: stats-filter-1.13.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: tcp-stats-filter-1.13.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: stats-filter-1.14.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: tcp-stats-filter-1.14.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: stats-filter-1.15.istio-system checked successfully
✔ EnvoyFilter: tcp-stats-filter-1.15.istio-system checked successfully
✔ ValidatingWebhookConfiguration: istio-validator-istio-system.istio-system checked successfully

Checked 15 custom resource definitions
Checked 2 Istio Deployments
✔ Istio is installed and verified successfully
```